# How to Ask user to Choose Language between French and English?

Tags: ios, ipad, localization, runtime, program-entry-point

I need to ask the user to choose language between french and English In Application Runtime or Before the application Starts?

1. In runtime Does localisation applies only after restarting the app?
2. Can I add Some alert in Main.m?

Like the Below

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Language"
                                                  message:@"2 Options"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"French", @"English", nil];
[message show];
```

In clickedButtonAtIndex Method:

```
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"French"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr",@"en",nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"English"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en",@"fr",nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
}
```

Comment: Why would you ask the user and not just use their preferred system language?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried to fix it? This question currently seems to be about app design rather than a specific problem.

Comment: @Robotic Cat I have App which localises french and english ...before logging to app need to make sure which is his /her preferred language for the application.

Comment: @012346: OK sounds fine to me - but that is not what I asked. What bugs or errors are you having? The question seems to be about app design at the moment.

Comment: @Robotic Cat If the Do it with using Uisegmentedcontrol in LoginViewController ,some interface builders will still use the system default language not the Specified lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot show an alert to the user before the application launch . Instead in the home screen / Launch screen you can use a switch control to switch between the languages .

Comment: I used this ...Some interface builder will not change the language in runtime ...once we kill the app & reopen then it switches

Comment: If you have only two language as option , load a default language and turn the switch to ON state. Use localizable strings if you face issues with interface builder

Comment: Do u mean using base internationalization